# Matching and sorting similar values in multiple Excel columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have four columns with numerical data in Excel. I need to align matching numbers adjacent to one another across the 4 columns and output all numbers that exist in all columns, i.e. four times, into column E as follows:

```
A     B   C   D   E
100  100 100 100 100
101  101
102  102 102 102 102
103
104  104 104 104 104
105  105 105
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more clearly? What do you expect the output to be? Also, what have you tried so far? Please post any relevant code, formulas, and/or attempts and what did and did not work.  Then we'd be able to help point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

On E2 enter the formula:

```
=IF(AND(A2=B2,A2=C2,A2=D2,A2<>""),A2,"")
```

Checks if all cells are equal and not null and return one of them.

You can drag it to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

In E2 count the number of entries in A2 to D2 that match A2. This should be 4
Additionally ensure that A2 is not empty.

If both conditions are true then return A2, otherwise display an empty cell.

```
=IF(AND(A2<>"",COUNTIF(A2:D2,"="&A2)=4),A2,"")
```